# RxSwift cannot recognize a subscribe method

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift for my iOS app.

I have a function which returns an `Observable` of items called `Repository`.

```
func search(query: String) -> Observable<Repository>
```

Basically it makes a network request to github to download the repositories given a search query.

Now, when I call this function, I follow the example in [RxSwift documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#creating-your-own-observable-aka-observable-sequence):

```
search(queryText).subscribeNext({ repo in
            print(repo)
        })
```

But Xcode says

> Cannot invoke 'subscribeNext' with an argument list of type '((Repository) -> ())'

That's weird because that's what Xcode suggests to sue when I use autocompletion. I already tried clean and re-build. I get the same kind of error even if I use another subscribe method.

So, what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function subscribeNext is of type

`((E) -> Void) -> Disposable`

The closure you provide is of correct type.
Maybe the place you call subscribeNext is not expecting a 
`Disposable`?

Comment: Great! Yes the error was completely misleading. That code was wrapped into a function with no returning type. Adding the Disposable type on the function return solved the problem.